# rxjs 6 filter after map show filter is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I am trying to filter Data after I use map, but I get an error that says:

> data.favorite.filter is not a function

Where am I wrong?

**the DB structure**:

```
uid{
   name
   age
   favorite{
            id{
               name
               }
            }
    }
```

```
this.db.getDataObj("/Profile/" + this.uid).pipe(
map(data => 
  data.favorite.filter(c=> 
    c.name === this.name))).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: We don't know what that endpoint returns, so we can't tell you where you're wrong. Evidently it's not an array. Maybe try logging out data, or looking at the response details in the network tab? Or were you trying to filter the stream, rather than an array in the stream?

Comment: Looks like map is not needed and it could work with `.pipe(filter(..`

Comment: @F.G. we don't know, it depends whether the OP is trying to filter the stream, or map a filter over arrays in the stream. Either could be a possibility.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right.

Comment: ok, I edit the code. Maybe now it will be clearer. in the favorite, I have few id's of other members and I want to filter it by name.

Comment: Your update shows that data.favorite is an object. Not an array. There is no filter method on objects. Of course, what you posted is neither valid JS, nor valid JSON, so we have to make guesses.